# Switch TargetActivity programmatically

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an activity alias that leads to one of my activities.

```
    <activity-alias
        android:name="LauncherOne"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:targetActivity="org.test.app.LauncherActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity-alias>
```

I want to be able to choose which activity it goes to, so how can I change the targetActivity programatically? 
I can't really find a workaround, because I cant enable/disable two different targetactivities as it would forget the default launcher every time.
And I haven't found a way to switch acitivities that doesn't cost some performance in my app.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to choose which activity it goes to, so how can I change the targetActivity programatically?

You can't. That information is baked into the manifest and cannot be changed at runtime.

Workaround: Have one activity that is your launcher activity. Have that activity use `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` as a theme, so it has no UI. Have that activity launch the "real" activity based on whatever criteria you choose, then `finish()` itself so that it is no longer in the back stack. Roughly speaking, this is the same approach that would be used by an app that had a splash screen activity that then decided what activity to go to next, just without the actual splash screen UI.